# Is Char.ConvertFromUtf32(0x20) anything other than string(' ')?

Tags: c#, utf

Can you imagine an environment where this return false?

```
var x = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(0x20);
var y = " ";
return x == y;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `x` and `y` are strings containing a single space.  They should always be equal.

Comment: Thank you. I wondered if space is always 0x20-coded, even when Codepage is f.e cyrillic?

Comment: @Kirsten " " is 0x20 in UTF32 (which is what you were using). Codepages do not apply to UTF32. Each Codepage is an encoding, UTF32 is another encoding. Also, Codepages are equal from 0x20 to 0x7F - Although there are other characters that are also whitespace, have a look at [Char.IsWhiteSpace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx). [You should know this, no excuse.](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)